# How can I make code of tikzpicture to plot the graph of $\sin x$ as shown in the figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-cd

I want to plot the graph of sin(x), getting the degrees on the *x-axis* as shown in the figure. I tried like this, but it is not like what I want. Can someone help providing me the code?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=2.5in,axis equal image,
xmax=3.5,ymax=1.2,
axis lines=middle,
enlargelimits,
axis line style={shorten >=-0.25cm,shorten <=-0.25cm,latex-latex},
ticklabel style={fill=white},
xtick={0,1,2}, ytick={0,0.5,1},
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
clip=false,]
\addplot[domain=0:2.5,mark=none,samples=200] {(sin(deg(x)))} node[fill=white, right]{$y=\sin(x)$};
\draw [fill=black] (1,0.845) circle (1.50pt);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I know how to plot the points in shown in figure, but I don't know how to get degrees on the x-axis.

Comment: I think perhaps that you added the image while the code was selected, you can see that all `[`/`]` in your code has been replaced by `\[`/`\]`. This happens because brackets in the alt-text for the image has to be escaped with backslashes in the markdown code. I'll fix it now, but it's something to take into account in the future :).

Comment: Have you try to use GeoGebra ? It is very efficient for specific plots. You can export the plot in TikZ format.

Comment: @projetmbc I have tried there, but the graph is not beautiful like I have shared in picture, that is why I tried some thing I shared

Comment: OT: I've to say, maybe due to some perspective issue, but the picture posted looks kind of odd to me. The maximum doesn't seem to be at 90° nor the minimum at 270°. Is it some polynomial approximation of sin(x)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you want degrees on the x-axis, I think it makes sense to plot using degrees as well. So instead of `domain=0:2.5` and `sin(deg(x))`, use `domain=0:360` and `sin(x)`. When you do this you need to remove `axis equal image`.

Having done that, you just need to format the ticklabels. By using `xticklabel` you can set the general format for the ticklabels, so to add a degree sign you can add the following to the axis options:

```
xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^{\circ}$}
```

`\tick` contains the x-value at the ticks, so use `\pgfmathprintnumber` to format the number, and add a degree sign with the normal `^{\circ}`. (Note this is different from `xticklabels`, with an `s` at the end, where you write a list of the ticklabels you want.)

You need to change the `xtick` setting you already have of course, I replaced it with `xtick distance=90` which gives you a tick every 90 degrees. If you want more frequent tick you should increase the width of the plot.

To get markers at specific points, one way is to add a second addplot like this:

```
\addplot[only marks,mark=*,samples at={0,90,...,360}] {sin(x)};
```

Here the x-values are stated explicitly with the `samples at` key. An alternative method is to use the `mark repeat` key, which lets you have markers at every nth sample point:

```
\addplot[
   domain=0:360,
   samples=181, % with domain=0:360 and 181 samples you get a sample every 2 degrees
   mark=*,
   mark repeat=45 % add a mark for every 45 sample, meaning you get a mark every 90 degreees
   ] {sin(x)} node[fill=white, right=2mm, pos=0.35]{$y=\sin(x)$};
```

Irrelevant sidenote: when loading `pgfplots`, you don't need `tikz` and `pgf` in addition, they will be loaded by `pgfplots` anyway.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=2.5in,
  xmax=380,ymax=1.2,
  axis lines=middle,
  enlargelimits,
  axis line style={shorten >=-0.25cm,shorten <=-0.25cm,latex-latex},
  ticklabel style={fill=white},
  ytick={-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1},
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel=$y$,
  clip=false,
  xtick distance=90,
  xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^{\circ}$}
]

\addplot[
   domain=0:360,
   samples=181, % with domain=0:360 and 181 samples you get a sample every 2 degrees
   mark=*,
   mark repeat=45 % add a mark for every 45 sample, meaning you get a mark every 90 degreees
   ] {sin(x)} node[fill=white, right=2mm, pos=0.35]{$y=\sin(x)$};


% alternative method
%\addplot[domain=0:360,mark=none,samples=100] {sin(x)} node[fill=white, right=2mm, pos=0.35]{$y=\sin(x)$};
%\addplot[only marks,mark=*,samples at={0,90,...,360}] {sin(x)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Compile with Asymptote. [asymptote.ualberta.ca](http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/)

```
import graph;
size(10cm,5cm,false);

real sinx(real x){return sin(x);}
path g=graph(sinx,0,2pi,350);
draw(g);

draw(Label("$x$",EndPoint,black),(-1,0)--(2*pi+0.5,0),blue,Arrow);
label(Label("$x'$",BeginPoint,black),(-1,0)--(2*pi+0.5,0));
draw(Label("$y$",EndPoint,black),(0,-1.5)--(0,1.5),darkgreen,Arrow);
label(Label("$y'$",BeginPoint,black),(0,-1.5)--(0,1.5));

real marginx=0.1, marginy=0.07;

for (int i: new int[]{-1,1}){
draw(scale(0.6)*Label("$"+(string) i+"$",Relative(0)),(0,i)-(marginx,0)--(0,i)+(marginx,0));
}
for (int i=0; i<=360; i=i+30){
draw(scale(0.6)*Label((i != 0) ? "$"+(string) i+"^{\circ}$" : " ",Relative(0),black),(radians(i),0)-(0,marginy)--(radians(i),0)+(0,marginy),blue);
dot((radians(i),sinx(radians(i))), (i == 0 || i == 360) ? blue : black);
}
label("$y=\sin x$" +" on " + "$[0,2\pi]$", (radians(130),-1.5));
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Similar to @Torbjørn T. [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554458/how-to-can-i-make-a-code-of-tikzpicture-to-plot-the-graph-of-sin-x-as-shown-i/554467#554467) (+1):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} % recent version is 1.17
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    x=0.25mm,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={Latex-Latex},
    xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={anchor=west},
    ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={anchor=south},
    %
    xmin=-25,   xmax=380,
    ymin=-1.25, ymax=1.25,
    ticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize},
    xtick distance=30,
    samples at={0,30,...,360},
    smooth
                ]
\addplot +[very thick] {sin(x)};
\node[above right] at (30,-1) {$y=\sin(x)$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]