# Coloring cartesian axes differently

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, axis

Starting from this question, [How to can I make a code of tikzpicture to plot the graph of $\sin x$ as shown in figure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554458/how-to-can-i-make-a-code-of-tikzpicture-to-plot-the-graph-of-sin-x-as-shown-i), and considering the same image, it is possible to see that there are different colors, for the axis: cyan for `x`-axis, magenta for the function `sin(x)` and green pine for `y`-axis.

[image]

Taking, for example, the MWE of @Torbjørn T.:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=2.5in,
  xmax=380,ymax=1.2,
  axis lines=middle,
  enlargelimits,
  axis line style={shorten >=-0.25cm,shorten <=-0.25cm,latex-latex},
  ticklabel style={fill=white},
  ytick={-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1},
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel=$y$,
  clip=false,
  xtick distance=90,
  xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^{\circ}$}
]

\addplot[
   domain=0:360,
   samples=181, % with domain=0:360 and 181 samples you get a sample every 2 degrees
   mark=*,
   mark repeat=45 % add a mark for every 45 sample, meaning you get a mark every 90 degreees
   ] {sin(x)} node[fill=white, right=2mm, pos=0.35]{$y=\sin(x)$};


% alternative method
%\addplot[domain=0:360,mark=none,samples=100] {sin(x)} node[fill=white, right=2mm, pos=0.35]{$y=\sin(x)$};
%\addplot[only marks,mark=*,samples at={0,90,...,360}] {sin(x)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

or @Zarko, **is it possible to colored the axis in different mode**?

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} % recent version is 1.17
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    x=0.25mm,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={Latex-Latex},
    xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={anchor=west},
    ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={anchor=south},
    %
    xmin=-25,   xmax=380,
    ymin=-1.25, ymax=1.25,
    ticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize},
    xtick distance=30,
    samples at={0,30,...,360},
    smooth
                ]
\addplot +[very thick] {sin(x)};
\node[above right] at (30,-1) {$y=\sin(x)$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have seen the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) but I have not found nothing related to my question.

Comment: `x axis line style` and `y axis line style`,  see `sec 4.9.9` of the manual in p. 273

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck Thank you very much...now I have seen with your suggestion that there is also the option `separate axis lines=true` pag. 274. I have not seen because, peraphs, there are few examples with two different colors.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this has been resolved in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, @Sebastiano mentioned me in in his question ... Used code from my answer considering  @ZhiyuanLck comment become:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    x=0.25mm,
    axis lines=middle,
    separate axis lines,
    x axis line style={Latex-Latex, blue},
    y axis line style={Latex-Latex, red},
    axis on top,
%
    xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={anchor=west},
    ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={anchor=south},
    %
    xmin=-25,   xmax=380,
    ymin=-1.25, ymax=1.25,
    ticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize,  inner ysep=2pt,
                       fill=white, fill opacity=0.5, text opacity=1},
    xtick distance=30,
    samples at={0,30,...,360},
    xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\si{\degree}},  % <---
    smooth
                ]
\addplot +[very thick] {sin(x)};
\node[above right] at (30,-1) {$y=\sin(x)$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which compilation result yields to:

[image]

*Note*: all credits go to [ZhiyuanLck](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/201158/zhiyuanlck).

Comment: Thank you very much always....and again for @ZhiyuanLck. Best regards.